# Fix deleted transaction log file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I have made the biggest mistake and deleted the transaction log file. Is there a way to fix this issue? I have the backup file, is there a way to restore it or reset everything again?

[image]

Comment: Your connection string is wrong or server is not running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup contains the log file as well.

Just restore the database using tsql

`Restore database db_name from disk = ' path to backup file.bak' with replace, stats=10`

Based on your screenshot, it seems a connection issue .. you are not able to connect to SQL server with ssms.

Also, see this blog by Aaron https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'm not sure how to use that command in tsql; In the end, I reinstall the SQL Server and restore the backup!